# Is this method of proving energy is conserved in an LC oscillator correct?

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor, oscillator, energy

Assuming no energy loss due to heat or EM waves
$$U=\frac{Q^2}{2C} +\frac{LI^2}{2}$$
differentiating both sides with respect to time,
$$\frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{QdQ}{Cdt}+IL\frac{dI}{dT}$$

but we know that the power factor of an LC circuit is zero, which means $$\frac{dU}{dt}=0$$
thus energy is conserved in an ideal LC oscillator/circuit

where U= total enery of the system
.

Comment: Anything lossless converts no energy to heat. It's no more complicated than a definition of the terms.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but I recently had a test in which I wrote this a the proof, so wanted to confirm if it was correct

Comment: Energy cannot be conserved in an LC oscillator neither. In an ideal LC circuit but not in an oscillator.

Comment: I meant an ideal LC oscillator, my bad

Comment: Then by definition it is lossless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but we know that the power factor of an LC circuit is zero, which means \$\frac{dU}{dt}=0\$

No it doesn't. The LC circuit is lossless, which means that average power is 0, i.e.

$$<u(t)i(t)> = 0 $$

Let's assume that we initially charge up the capacitor with a voltage \$U_0\$, disconnect it from the source and connect it to the inductor at time \$t = 0\$. The voltage and current will be

$$u(t) = U_0\cos(\omega t), i(t)  = I_0\sin(\omega t)$$

where \$\omega = 1/\sqrt{LC}\$.

The instantaneous energies will be

$$E_C(t) = \frac{1}{2}CU_0^2\cos^2(\omega t), E_I(t)  \frac{1}{2}LI_0^2\sin^2(\omega t) $$

At \$t = k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} \$ all the energy is in the capacitor and at  \$t = (k+1/2)\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} \$ all the energy is on the inductor. In between, there is energy in both, but the sum  \$E_T = E_C + E_S\$ is always the same

$$E_T = E_C + E_S = \frac{1}{2}CU_0^2 = \frac{1}{2}LI_0^2$$

from which we can derive

$$I_0 = U_0\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}} $$

So lossless means

$$\frac{\partial E_t}{\partial t} = 0 $$

not
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = 0 $$

Comment: Thanks, but isn't U=E? (isn't U usually energy, or is it voltage in  engineering?)

Comment: I defined it as a voltage which is often used in engineering.

Comment: Notice that launching energy into the lossless resonator by the method outlined (charging a capacitor, then connecting to inductor) is the only way. A lossless resonator neither dissipates energy, *nor can it accept energy from outside*.

Comment: @Hilmar, I see, thanks!

Comment: @glen_geek, understood. Thank you!